# Wie können wir deutschen Muttersprachlern klarer machen, dass auf Deutsch zu fragen gestattet ist?

Tags: discussion, language

Wir sind uns alle einig, dass auf dieser Seite Fragen sowohl auf Englisch als auch auf Deutsch gestellt werden können.

Allerdings müssen wir immer wieder feststellen, dass neue Benutzer ihre Frage auf Englisch stellen – dann aber auch quasi sofort hinzufügen:

> I am a native German speaker …

Dies führt dann in der Regel zu einem Kommentar, in dem gefragt wird, warum denn die Frage nicht auf Deutsch geschrieben wurde. Offensichtlich ist es einigen neuen Nutzern nicht klar genug, dass das eine Option ist.

Wie können wir es insbesondere für Muttersprachler deutlicher machen, dass Fragen auf Deutsch.SE auch auf Deutsch gestellt werden können?

Comment: Siehe auch http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/1006/lets-make-the-tour-bilingual. Allerdings werden nur wenige Neulinge die Tour lesen (10% der User und kaum neue User haben den Informed-Badge), und vielmehr sofort auf die **bilingualen** Fragen auf der ersten Seite stoßen.

Comment: Auch relevant: [Should and can we make more clear to newcomers that we are bilingual?](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/640/2594)

Comment: Ich vermute es ist gar nicht so, dass die englischschreibenden Deutschmuttersprachler nicht *wüssten*, dass sie auch deutsch schreiben können. Sie schreiben einfach lieber englisch, weil das für sie anregender ist. Üblicherweise sind es ja Leute, die an Sprachen interessiert sind...  Wollte man deutsches Fragen in solchen Fällen fördern, müsste man irgendwo sehr klar annoncieren, dass Fragen nach Möglichkeit auf Deutsch zu stellen sind...

Answer (score 5):

Warum findest du es denn so wichtig, den deutschen Neulingen klar zu machen, dass man auch auf deutsch fragen kann?

**Sobald sie länger dabei sind, kriegen sie das sowieso mit.**

Außerdem macht es nichts, wenn die Fragen auf englisch gestellt sind, da es hier auch viele Leute gibt, die nicht so gut deutsch können.

*Und um ehrlich zu sein, verbessert es ihren Englisch-Wortschatz ;)*

Comment: Von manchen Usern kommen Kommentare wie »Warum stellst du in einem Deutsch-Forum Deutschen Muttersprachlern eine Frage über die deutsche Sprache auf Englisch?«, wobei jede Instanz von *deutsch* fett gesetzt ist. Ich finde, im Grunde haben diese Leute nicht unrecht; wenn es um die feineren Punkte der deutschen Sprache geht, und alle Parteien des Deutschen mächtig sind, ist Deutsch meines Erachtens zu bevorzugen.

Comment: German SE ist eine Ausnahme, aber nachdem SE im Prinzip eine englischsprachige Seite ist, darf man davon ausgehen, dass die meisten dieses Sprache auch beherrschen. Ich habe jedenfalls kein Problem damit,wenn auch "native speakers" ihre Fragen in Englisch stellen. Abgesehen davon, dass ich das bisher nicht als Problem empfunden habe.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass eine Deutsch-Forum sich unbedingt als Ziel setzen sollte, den Englisch-Wortschatz der Besucher zu verbessern. Dafür bietet das Internet woanders tausende Möglichkeiten, die besser geeignet sind.

Comment: Es ist zwar richtig, dass hier auch viele Leute sind, die nicht so gut Deutsch können, aber eben auch viele, die nicht so gut (oder gar nicht) Englisch können. Derzeit versuchen viele Menschen, die aus dem Arabischen Raum zu uns gekommen sind, Deutsch zu lernen. Müssen diese Menschen wirklich erst Englisch lernen, um hier Fragen und Antworten über Deutsch lesen zu können? Das wäre ja absurd!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast An sich bin ich bei dir - ich finde es auch absurd, wenn ein Deutscher eine Frage zur deutschen Sprache auf Englisch stellt. Gegenfrage zu deinem "Arabischen Raum"-Punkt: Viele *können* Englisch. Müssen diese Menschen erst Deutsch lernen, um Fragen und Antworten über Deutsch lesen zu können?

Comment: @tofot: Ja. Sie wollen (oder müssen) ja ohnehin Deutsch lernen. Hier geht es ja nicht um Anfängerfragen. Bei dem meisten Fragen, die auf German.SE behandelt werden, kann man getrost davon ausgehen, das jemand, der sich mit solchen Fragen beschäftigt, schon gut genug Deutsch kann, um geschriebenes Deutsch lesen und verstehen zu können.

Answer (score 2):

Vielleicht helfen diese Argumente:

1. Dies hier ist ein Forum, das sich mit der deutschen Sprache beschäftigt. Alle anderen Sprachen sind als Thema der Fragen ausdrücklich off-topic. Dies betrifft ausdrücklich auch Englisch.
2. Jeder, der dieses Forum besucht, hat Interesse an der deutschen Sprache. Es gibt keinen Grund, ein besonderes Interesse der Besucher an anderen Sprachen anzunehmen.
3. **Die Fragen werden in diesem Forum so gut wie ausschließlich von deutschen Muttersprachlern beantwortet.** Diese Antwortgebern würden sich freuen, wenn sie Fragen *über* ihre Muttersprache auch *in* ihrer Muttersprache lesen und beantworten könnten.
   <sub>*(Es wird hier nämlich als gute Sitte angesehen, Fragen in derselben Sprache zu beantworten, in der sie gestellt wurden.)*</sub>

---

Die Behauptungen 1 und 2 liegen auf der Hand. Sie lassen sich leicht aus den Zweck dieses Forums ableiten.

Um das dritte Argument zu belegen, habe ich mir die User angesehen, die hier die meisten Antworten geschrieben haben. Dazu habe ich heute (17. Juni 2017) die User mit den größten Reputationen insgesamt ([user, reputation, all](https://german.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)) und innerhalb des laufenden Jahres ([user, reputation, year](https://german.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year)) ausgewertet. Ich habe mir pro Liste jeweils die 36 höchstgereihten User angesehen (also alle User auf der jeweiligen Seite 1 der Auswertung) und habe mir die Profile dieser User angesehen. Aus diesen Profilen habe ich zunächst das Herkunftsland und die Anzahl der Antworten notiert.

Anschließend habe ich aus den Benutzern, die in mindestens einer der beiden Auswertungen enthalten waren, jene 40 ausgewählt, die am meisten Antworten verfasst haben.

Zur Abschätzung der Muttersprache bin ich davon ausgegangen, dass die Muttersprache von jemanden, der angegeben hat, aus Deutschland oder Österreich zu sein, Deutsch ist. Dort, wo diese Herkunftsangabe gefehlt hat, und dort, wo sie etwas anders als D oder Ö war, habe ich mir angesehen, in welcher Sprache der jeweilige Benutzer selbst Fragen gestellt hat. Bei jenen, die selbst keine Fragen gestellt haben, habe ich nachgesehen, ob deutschsprachige Antworten gegeben wurde, und ob die sprachliche Qualität dieser Antworten der eines Muttersprachlers entspricht.

All dies ergibt diese Liste:

1. **Hubert Schölnast**
   853 Antworten, aus Österreich, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
2. **Jan**
   615 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
3. **Takkat**
   609 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
4. **EM1**
   500 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
5. **Emanuel**
   419 Antworten, *(keine Ortsangabe)*, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
6. **user unknown**
   397 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
7. **rogermue**
   364 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
8. **tofro**
   354 Antworten, *(keine Ortsangabe)*, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
9. **splattne**
   315 Antworten, aus Italien (Südtirol), Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
10. **Ingmar**
    293 Antworten, aus Österreich, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
11. **Thorsten Dittmar**
    261 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
12. **Carsten S**
    255 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
13. **Tom Au**
    239 Antworten, aus den USA, Muttersprache: **Englisch**
14. **chirlu**
    236 Antworten, *(keine Ortsangabe)*, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
15. **Toscho**
    236 Antworten, *(keine Ortsangabe)*, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
16. **Matthias**
    234 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
17. **Wrzlprmft**
    233 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
18. **guidot**
    212 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
19. **c.p.**
    198 Antworten, *(keine Ortsangabe)*, Muttersprache: **Spanisch**
20. **Stephie**
    184 Antworten, *(keine Ortsangabe)*, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
21. **Loong**
    171 Antworten, aus Finnland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
22. **Janka**
    163 Antworten, *(keine Ortsangabe)*, Muttersprache: **unklar, vermutlich Englisch**
23. **Robert**
    152 Antworten, *(keine Ortsangabe)*, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
24. **Hans Adler**
    149 Antworten, *(keine Ortsangabe)*, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
25. **Kilian Foth**
    145 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
26. **tohuwawohu**
    135 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
27. **Crissov**
    126 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
28. **Pollitzer**
    125 Antworten, *(keine Ortsangabe)*, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
29. **OregonGhost**
    121 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
30. **dirkt**
    117 Antworten, *(keine Ortsangabe)*, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
31. **elena**
    117 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
32. **Phira**
    116 Antworten, *(keine Ortsangabe)*, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
33. **Christian Geiselmann**
    103 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
34. **John Smithers**
    100 Antworten, *(keine Ortsangabe)*, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
35. **knut**
    96 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
36. **Iris**
    90 Antworten, *(keine Ortsangabe)*, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
37. **Barth Zalewsky**
    78 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
38. **Uwe**
    72 Antworten, *(keine Ortsangabe)*, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
39. **Jan**
    64 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **Deutsch**
40. **Ad Infinitum**
    58 Antworten, aus Deutschland, Muttersprache: **unklar**

Auch wenn ich mich vielleicht in dem einen oder anderen Fall bei der Vermutung hinsichtlich der Muttersprache geirrt haben sollte, und wenn vielleicht auch andere User in die Top-40-Antwortgeber gehören sollten, (nämlich wenn sie nicht zu den oben beschrieben Usern mit den höchsten Reputationen gehören, aber trotzdem mehr Antworten als der derzeit letztgereihte Benutzer geschrieben haben), so macht diese Liste doch recht eindrucksvoll klar, welche Muttersprache fast alle Menschen sprechen, die hier Fragen beantworten.

Diese Liste deckt 9305 Antworten ab. Davon wurden 8705 Antworten (93,6%) von 37 Menschen gegeben, deren Muttersprache Deutsch ist. 239 Antworten (2,6%) wurden von einem englischsprachigen Benutzer gegeben. Die restlichen 361 Antworten (3,9%) wurden von zwei Personen gegeben, die - wie ich glaube - eine andere Muttersprache als Deutsch haben (nämlich Russisch und Englisch), deren Deutschkenntnisse aber meiner persönlichen Einschätzung nach denen von deutschen Muttersprachlern kaum nachstehen.

Comment: @AdInfinitum: Du hast soeben diesen Beitrag editiert und dabei ausdrücklich angegeben, dass (offenbar auch dir selbst) unklar ist, was deine Muttersprache ist. Wie ist das zu verstehen? Du wirst doch selbst eine gewisse Ahnung davon haben, welche Sprache(n) du als Kleinkind gelernt hast und heute fließend beherrscht.

Comment: @AdInfinitum: Du hättest ja die Möglichkeit, es richtigzustellen.